# Symfony2 on nginx shared hosting

Tags: symfony, nginx, http-status-code-404, hosting, shared

i've a symfony 2.3.16 project which work great on localhost.
But today i wanted to host it on my remote server : its a shared hosting on nginx 1.4.7

i've changed the public folder (from /web to /public_html : still working great on localhost)
i've cleared then deleted the dev and prod cache,
added my remote IP to app_dev.php and activate the debuger in app.php

and then uploaded all files to my shared hosting.
the tree is like this :
    app
    bin
    public_html
        - bundles
        - app.php
        - app_dev.php
        - config.php
        - .htaccess
    src
    vendor

and when i try to access some pages, i've always ended with a 404 Not Found error.

here, you can see : http://dojonantais.cwebh.org/app.php/admin/

i have no route defined for /
my app/config/routing.yml is like this :
    dnAdmin:
        resource:   "@dnAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:     /admin

also, when i try dev environnement http://dojonantais.cwebh.org/app_dev.php
it says there is no route for /, which is logic, but i've another error with the debug bar :
    An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).
    Do you want to open the profiler?

and when i open the profiler : 404 not found

again, i can access the config.php and it says my server is ok to run Symfony, but cant access the configurator (404 error)

So, what is missing?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So, problems coming from my remote host on nginx.

i change the host to a 1and1 server and all is ok.